# Block repeat button clicks on website

Tags: php, button

I have a site written with PHP: how can I prevent a user from clicking a button multiple times?

For example, I have an upvote button similar to the one on the left of this post. I want non-logged-in users to be able to upvote, but only once. What strategies can i use to prevent the user from clicking it twice?

Simply deactivating the button after first click isnt enough, since they would then be able to visit the page again, or refresh their cache, etc, etc.

Comment: You could store the status of the user to a SESSION, COOKIE, or a database field. You will need to use AJAX so you can stop the action after the first click.

Comment: You can only limit their ability to vote multiple times. If you don't know who the user is, and the user clears their browser cache/local storage you have no chance knowing who it is. And even then, the user could just use a proxy, TOR or similar to appear as a different user.

Comment: You can allow one vote per IP address, but it is not really a good idea (we are out of ipv4 addr, a lot of people has the same public ip so just one of them could vote). Ask them to signup/login or better email address/phone number

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way for you to do this is to tie the vote to the users IP address in a database.

AND setting a cookie on that computer. That way, you lock it down from two different corners so that you aren't limiting others on the same connection.

You're not really going to be able to fool - proof this successfully without a user login system.

Comment: But IP != a user. Normally today a public IP is at least a household, at most it can be an entire company, campus or large amounts of people on mobile networks.

Comment: what about implement a log in process and/or maintain session state? or even create a DB field / user log in.

Comment: How about block a unique ID which identifies a user?

Comment: Lol unique ID would require something to tie to it. You're not really going to be able to successfully and fool proof do this without a user login system. The only way to really do this is to set a cookie and then restrict it in the DB by IP and then check the IP and cookie to see if the user has voted on something,

Comment: @DerekPollard what if I delete the cookie?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Like I said, the only way to successfully do this is what I said. Without a login, there is no real convenient way to do this,

Comment: @Script47 problem is getting the unique ID which is that user only. In many cases you can finger print the browser, but not always. And it would make for a horrible UX to have the site "broken" because you have a similar browser setup as someone else.

Comment: @DerekPollard I can't see how storing the IP works. If I delete the cookie, then what do you do? You can see that the IP has voted, but that was clearly not me (no cookie), so... Afaik there is no way to do this without some kind of authentication. edit: ok, saw your edit - must just be some misunderstanding here, we're clearly on the same page :)

Comment: Which is what I said in my original comment LOL.

Comment: So what I take from this is that there really is no fool-proof way to do this. It requires login to be 100% tracked. Session/Cookies tracking should be setup as a simple block for most people. IP address would be the best alternative if it was guaranteed that each visitor had a unique IP.

Comment: IP+COOKIE is really the only (crappy) alternative because once the users cookies get cleared, they can vote again. Login system is the only true way to make it distinguishable.